# How to set SegmentedButton BorderRadius zero in flutter?

Tags: flutter

How to set SegmentedButton  BorderRadius zero in flutter?

```dart
SegmentedButton<int>(
        segments: const <ButtonSegment<int>>[
          ButtonSegment<int>(
            value: 0,
            label: Text('item1'),
          ),
          ButtonSegment<int>(
            value: 1,
            label: Text('item2'),
          ),
        ],
        selected: <int>{_selectedIndex},
        onSelectionChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _selectedIndex = value.first;
          });
        },
        showSelectedIcon: false,
      )
```

get buttons with radius.

And this is my flutter's version(maybe some answer cloud work well in version 2 so I update it)

```bash
$ flutter --version                                              0ms  11:01 (Wed) 
Flutter 3.13.6 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision ead455963c (4 weeks ago) • 2023-09-26 18:28:17 -0700
Engine • revision a794cf2681
Tools • Dart 3.1.3 • DevTools 2.25.0
```

Answer (score 2):

From chatgpt I get the ansewer **custom style**

```dart
SegmentedButton<int>(
        segments: const <ButtonSegment<int>>[
          ButtonSegment<int>(
            value: 0,
            label: Text('item1'),
          ),
          ButtonSegment<int>(
            value: 1,
            label: Text('item2'),
          ),
        ],
        selected: <int>{_selectedIndex},
        onSelectionChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _selectedIndex = value.first;
          });
        },
        showSelectedIcon: false,
        style: ButtonStyle(
          shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
            const RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the BorderRadius of a SegmentedButton to zero in Flutter, you can wrap the SegmentedButton widget with a Container and set the borderRadius property of the Container to zero. Here's an example:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
  ),
  child: SegmentedButton<int>(
    segments: const <ButtonSegment<int>>[
      ButtonSegment<int>(
        value: 0,
        label: Text('item1'),
      ),
      ButtonSegment<int>(
        value: 1,
        label: Text('item2'),
      ),
    ],
    selected: <int>{_selectedIndex},
    onSelectionChanged: (value) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedIndex = value.first;
      });
    },
    showSelectedIcon: false,
  ),
)
```

In this example, the Container wraps the SegmentedButton, and the borderRadius property of the BoxDecoration is set to BorderRadius.zero, which sets the border radius to zero for all corners of the container. This effectively sets the border radius of the SegmentedButton to zero.

Comment: Sorry , it seem to be not work . And I get the answer **custom the style** from ChatGpt lol, I should try it first then ask this question.